# Not a single-group group function, with aggregate functions in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS "Number of Employees",
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM hire_date) AS "Month Hired",
    AVG(salary)
FROM
    hr.employees;
```

It gives me the error: `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`. I have tried other resources and answers from other people, but they don't work in my case.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Number of Employees",
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM hire_date) AS "Month Hired",
       AVG(salary)
FROM hr.employees
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM hire_date);
```

There may be reasons why you are only interested in the hire month.  However, normally, you would also want the year.  In Oracle, this would commonly be accomplished using `TO_CHAR()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month_hired,
       COUNT(*) AS num_empoyees,
       AVG(salary)
FROM hr.employees
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'YYYY-MM')
ORDER BY month_hired;
```

Comment: Yes, I was going to add the year as a condition to filter, but I wanted to make sure that it would run before I would do that.